# Calculating Percentage

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, intersection

I am trying to calculate the area of `floodplain` within `property`. So when I do intersect it merges the two layers together where they intersect. But from there I don't know how to calculate the areas in the new layer, and then add that data back to `property`.

Essentially what I am trying to do is isolate the properties that have a certain percentage of floodplain in them.

The steps I have in my head but am lost on what tools to utilize to achieve my desired outcome:

1. Create a new field in `property` called "true_area"
2. Do calculate geometry to determine the area
3. Intersect `floodplain` and `property` to create `intersection`
4. Create a new field in `intersection` called "flood_area"
5. Do calculate geometry to determine the area
6. Some how merge `property` and `intersection` based on retained fields containing the address
7. Create a new field in `property` called "percentage"
8. Divide "flood_area" by "true_area" to get decimal value
9. Convert to percentage with calculate field
10. Export data to new layer "Where percentage is greater than or equal to 20

This is the scenario I believe I need to go to have the outcome I am looking for.
I do not know how to do coding, this is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Summarise intersect by fid_property as case field, area totals. Join output table to property.

Comment: Yes! This worked. I was messing up the join. Thanks!